# How to add a <span> in a middle of a sentence when using a flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Given a flex container that contains a sentence, I'd like to wrap one of the words with a `<span>` for some additional styling. Example:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is <span>not</span> a very long sentence.
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see, the sentence breaks after the `<span>`.

The desired outcome is:

[image]

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  white-space: pre;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>This </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span class="red">not </span>
  <span>a </span>
  <span>very </span>
  <span>long </span>
  <span>sentence.</span>
</div>
```

How would you solve this?

Comment: You could wrap the sentence in any other tag like  <p> inside your main parent div which has style display : flex

Comment: Just don't use flex on the text containers?

Comment: Also could use display: inline; instead of flex

Comment: by using display:flex on that text container you're basically dividing it into 3 diferent flex items: anonymous text before the span, the span itself, and everything after. The outcome is exactly what you're telling it to do, the browser checks if *everything after the span* can fit in a single line, and as it can't, wraps it to the next columns. Also display the typical white-space "issue" with flexbox. Why are you trying to use flexbox on this one?

Comment: Just remove the `display` and `flex-wrap` properties from the `div`. I've added a solution recommending/explaining this. There's no need to use `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with   `display: inline-block;`

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is <span>not</span> a very long sentence.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the contents of the flexbox div within a span

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 190px;
}

span#inner {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>This is <span id="inner">not</span> a very long sentence</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the text in a `<p>` so that the span inherits the properties of paragraph besides it being the right way of handling the HTML semantically. Correct me if I am wrong but it adds accessibility to it.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is <span>not</span> a very long sentence.</p>
</div>
```

Option 2: Don't wrap the `div` in flex. Use `inline-block`

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is <span>not</span> a very long sentence.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the `div` do what it naturally does, so just define a `width` and the desired `border`.

There's no reason to give the `div` any `display` property, especially not `display: flex`.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 190px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is <span>not</span> a very long sentence.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works, but doesn't really explain the question.

For spacing, all `inline` elements are interpreted as normal texts in each tag.

```css
 div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 190px;
}
span {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is    <span>not</span>     a very long    sentence.
</div>
```

*It's like* that this `div` element has three "Text Nodes" and the word "not" is just *separated* from the rest of the text in order to have control over it (in CSS, JS).

The default `div` (with `display: block`) treats these "three nodes" like one line text in the matter of spacing, which is the action of removing all white-spaces and leaving only one. So the (single) space between the words `is` and `<span>` and between the words `</span>` and `a very` are preserved like a normal white-space in a sentence.

But when you set the `div`'s `display` to `flex`, Each text node acts as a column for this new flex-box and all the space between them is removed.

```css
 div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 190px;
    display: flex;
}
span {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is    <span>not</span>     a very long    sentence.
</div>
```

In my opinion it's usually not wise to put text nodes directly inside flex parents.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other elements within the parent div which could rely on **flex property** of the parent div. Just add property of display: inline-block to the paragraph
css

```
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 190px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

html

```
<div>
  <span>This is <span>not</span> a very long sentence</span>
</div>
```